# Hibernate Search in Jboss 7 - Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.search.jpa.Search

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, jboss7.x, hibernate-search

When running:

> FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager =
>   Search.getFullTextEntityManager(em);

I get this in Runtime:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.hibernate.search.jpa.Search

In my pom.xml I have:

> ```
>    <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
>         <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
>         <artifactId>hibernate-search</artifactId>
>         <version>4.0.0.Final</version>
>     </dependency>
> ```

Running Maven dependecy-analyze:

> [WARNING] Used undeclared dependencies found:
>
> [WARNING]
>   org.hibernate:hibernate-search-orm:jar:4.0.0.Final:compile
>
> [WARNING]    org.jboss.shrinkwrap:shrinkwrap-api:jar:1.1.2:test
>
> [WARNING]    javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1:provided
>
> [WARNING]
>   org.jboss.arquillian.container:arquillian-container-test-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:test
>
> [WARNING]    javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.0.0.GA:provided
>
> [WARNING]    org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:jar:3.4.0:compile
>
> [WARNING]
>   org.jboss.arquillian.junit:arquillian-junit-core:jar:1.1.0.Final:test
>
> [WARNING] Unused declared dependencies found:
>
> [WARNING]    org.hibernate:hibernate-c3p0:jar:5.0.0.Final:compile
>
> [WARNING]
>   org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:4.2.0.Final:compile
>
> [WARNING]    org.hibernate:hibernate-search:jar:4.0.0.Final:compile
>
> [WARNING]
>   org.jboss.arquillian.junit:arquillian-junit-container:jar:1.1.0.Final:test
>
> [WARNING]
>   org.jboss.arquillian.protocol:arquillian-protocol-servlet:jar:1.1.0.Final:test

In my classpath I have:

```
    > <classpathentry exported="true" kind="con"  path="org.eclipse.m2e.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER">        
    > <attributes>
    >           <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>                  
    >           <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.dependency" value="/WEB-INF/lib"/>
    >       </attributes>   
    ></classpathentry>
```